# the answer to my request does not give the same string as the one displayed

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, request

I am making a call to an api,
the return of the answer gives me a string (that I print)

however when I want to do a check, it doesn't work

there is my code:

```
def get_status_stripe_dependencies():
    request = requests.get("https://status.stripe.com/current/full")

    if request.status_code != 200:
        return (False)    
    

    request_json = (request.json())
    reponse = (request_json["message"])
    reponse = str(reponse.strip())
    print("reponse", reponse, "aas")


    if ("All Services are online") in reponse:
        return True

    return "WHYYYYYYYYYY"
```

my print gives me "All Services are online"
BUT MY return is "whyyyyyyyyyyy"

I tried to remove invisible chars but it doesn't work
if someone has the solution.

Thanks for yours answers

Comment: `WHYYYYY` : Because the return of the website is in lower case. `in` is case sensitive. you can just change the operator in the condition or do this `"All Services are online".lower() in reponse.lower():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `S` of `Services` is in uppercase and the `response` returned this string `All services are online`, so you may change your test to:

```
if "all services are online" in reponse.lower():
        return True
```